# How to sync the UI with data changes in my code

Tags: android, flutter, dart

the code is running correctly but the problem is I don't see the UI changes according to the data. as you may notice from my code, in _buildWidget function my cards are made and the shareTag function in the stack is called but at first, because the  variable is not true then container is not visible but after the user click on one of the cards I would expect that the isSelected turns to true and then I could see the container in that stack that but it doesn't happen ... I have debugged the code and I noticed that the isSelected variable turn to right correctly every time the users tap on the card but I don't see any changes on UI

```
  Activity activity;
  List<double> _cost;
  ActivityPeopleCard({this.activity});

  @override
  _ActivityPeopleCardState createState() => _ActivityPeopleCardState();
}

class _ActivityPeopleCardState extends State<ActivityPeopleCard> {
  int _peopleIndex = -1;
  List<int> _peopleIndexes = new List();
  List<int> _longPressed = new List();
  var _vlContainer;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _vlContainer = myListContainer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _vlContainer;
  }

  myListContainer() {
    return Container(
      height: height / 2.6,
      child: new GridView.builder(
        itemCount: widget.activity.peopleInvolved.length,
        gridDelegate:
            new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new GestureDetector(

              onTap: () => setState(() => {
               _priceSet(index),

              _buildWidget(index)
}),
              child: _buildWidget(index));
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildWidget(int index) {
    bool isSelected = _peopleIndexes.contains(index) ? true : false;

    return new Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
        elevation: 5.0,
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            height: height / 4,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: height / 15,
                  height: height / 15,

                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(height / 20),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
                  ),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(height / 15),
                      child: Image.asset(
                          widget.activity.peopleInvolved[index].imagePath,
                          fit: BoxFit.fill)), //CircleAvatar(
                ),
                Center(child: Text(widget.activity.peopleInvolved[index].name))
              ],
            ),
          ),
          shareTag(index)
        ]));
  }

  shareTag(index) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onLongPress: () => {
              enterPrice(index),
            },
        child: Visibility(
          visible: isSelected ? true : false,
          child: new Container(
              height: height / 2,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(height / 20),
                color: Colors.red.shade500.withOpacity(0.7),
              ),
              child: Center(
                  child: SizedBox(
                width: width / 4,
                height: height / 15,
                child: Center(
                  child: AutoSizeText(
                    "\$${ActivityPeopleCard._cost[index]}",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontFamily: 'Oxygen',
                        fontSize: height / 25),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    minFontSize: 5,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              ))),
        ));
  }

  enterPrice(int index) {
    //print("Long Pressed");
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            shape:
                RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            content: Form(
              //key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new TextFormField(
                    initialValue: ActivityPeopleCard._cost[index].toString(),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    cursorColor: secondColor,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      letterSpacing: 1,
                    ),
                    autofocus: true,
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      focusedBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                          borderSide: new BorderSide(color: secondColor)),
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: firstColor
                          //decorationColor: Colors.yellow
                          ),
                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.attach_money,
                        color: firstColor,
                      ),
                      labelText: "Cost",
                      border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.black87),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

although I have called the _buildWidget again on onTap function and the isSelected is true the ui is not updated

Comment: The code is a bit convoluted, and not all methods can be seen, so only judging from what's provided, but for your UI to change, you should change the value of `isSelected` inside `setState()`, which will trigger widget rebuild. Also, your `build` method just returns `_vlContainer` and it does no building, hence you don't see any change. Extract `isSelected` to be a class variable, then build your stuff in `build()` method, and widget that depends on that variable should change state after you call `setState()`

Comment: thanks for your answer but now the problem is the _cost list that is initialized in the ActivityPeopleCard constructor with zero (i didn't mention this initialization in the code) when the user tap on the cards and the visibility turn to true the user again can do a long tapped on the container  that is just turned to visible and then enterPrice function will be called and the showDialog box shows Alert dialog but when it happened _cost list again reinitialized by zero. it seems the ActivityPeopleCard called again... do you have any idea how could i keep my list value?